# Why can't I get a remote data source within an applet?

Tags: java, oracle, applet, weblogic, jndi

I trying to do a JNDI lookup on a data source that lives in Weblogic 10.3.5.

I have the following code:

```
    try {
    //jbInit();

    env.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7001");

    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
        javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/sandboxDS");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(conn != null){
        System.out.println("Got connection...");

        String colDescQuery =
        "select column1 from my_table where table_name = 'your_table' order by col_order_no";
        Statement colDescStmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet colDescRS = colDescStmt.executeQuery(colDescQuery);

        while (colDescRS.next()) {
        System.out.println(colDescRS.getString(1));
        }                 

    } else {
        System.out.println("No connection...");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run this code as a stand alone Java program it works perfectly. The connection is found and the query returns the expected results.

When I use the same code in an applet and run it from the JDeveloper applet viewer it hangs where the InitialContext is instantiated.  No exceptions are thrown, it simply hangs never to return.

Any ideas as to what is going on here? I have weblogic.jar and wlthint3client.jar in my classpath for both runs.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Applets have sandbox restrictions, so they cannot connect to the server other than where they were downloaded from.

Make sure your applet is also deployed to the same WebLogic Server that your JNDI data source is on.

Comment: Thanks. The code is being run from the JDeveloper applet viewer so the sandbox restrictions are not in place. For real deployment I plan on signing the applet.

Comment: Are you *certain* that JDeveloper does not use a sand-box for applets?  By default, the applet viewer does in recent times.